# New Ruby on Rails Setup : "Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm setting up a Ruby on Rails web development environment on a new machine (macOS Sierra v. 10.12.1).  I'm following the setup instructions here: [Setup Ruby On Rails on macOS 10.12 Sierra](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra).  When I check the newly installed rails version, I get the following:

```
$ rails --version
Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)
Rails 4.2.6
```

I haven't seen that second line before, and googling hasn't yielded any helpful results.  Background information: clean install of macOS 10.12.1; installed xcode via the App Store; installed Homebrew via the instructions on [its homepage](http://brew.sh/); installing Ruby, Rails, etc. via the first link I mentioned.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's due to a change in the latest version of Thor. https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0192-release-2016-11-26. Rails 5 is not affected. You can ignore the warning on Rails 4 and earlier.

Comment: Any way to get rid of the warning?

Comment: This may fix.
`$ gem install thor --version="0.19.1"`
`$ gem uninstall thor --version="0.19.4"` # check your version

Comment: @mgka you are the real MVP

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Rails 4.2.7, set up with RubyMine 7.1.3.

Adding `gem 'thor', '0.19.1'` to my Gemfile and then running `bundle update thor` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got past this error by installing `thor-0.19.4.`

`gem install "thor-0.19.4"`