# Ruby/Rails Deprecation warning: Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning rails and when I try run the server `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` on wsl, I received an error:

```
Deprecation warning: Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean).
This will be rejected in the future unless you explicitly pass the options `check_default_type: false` or call `allow_incompatible_default_type!` in your code
You can silence deprecations warning by setting the environment variable THOR_SILENCE_DEPRECATION.
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]...
```

I tried gem thor to 0.19.1 but the error it's the same.

How Can I fix it?

Obs.:
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
rails 4.2.5
ubuntu 18.04 on wsl

Gemfile.lock wasn't created.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read 
more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in 
views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in 
the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

https://gist.github.com/EricGPTI/8630fcf2591a1027bfa19908e7529779

Comment: Your gem file lock might be useful here for debugging....

Comment: I create a project using: rails _4.2.5_ new notebook, but the Gemfile.lock wasn't created.

Comment: Since this issue has to do with specific gem versions, the `Gemfile.lock` will list those versions exactly.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/538

Comment: I understood @GarrettMotzner, but the file Gemfile.lock was not created when I run my command to create project rails.

I see the link and trying to downgrade the thor to version '0.19.0' and '0.19.1' but the error happen yet!

Comment: If you are using bundler, after you run `bundle install`, it create the lock file. odd that it didn't...

Comment: I googled your error, and [this is the top result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40896670/1954610). Does that answer your question?

Comment: I tried it, but without success.  At the moment I am trying another way...

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I added a link for gist when I input the Gemfile.lock data, because here I get a error.